# Are these three lines from "Lieder" references to songs, too?

Tags: lyrics, meaning, adel-tawil

In the song *Lieder*, Adel Tawil references in almost each line a (usually popular) song.

The [German Wikipedia article about this song](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lieder_%28Lied%29#Lied) lists the references in a table. However, three lines are missing a reference:

- from the refrain:

  > Und ich singe diese Lieder,
- from the third strophe:

  > Ich sang nur noch für mich,

  > für ’ne unendlich lange Zeit.

Are these references, too?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think these are quotes from songs. The first quote just means "And I am singing these songs." The second quote is a reference to the time between the end of his boy band The Boyz and the founding of Ich+Ich with Annette Humpe. It translates to:

> I only sang for myself
>   for an infinitely long time

Then it continues "und dann traf ich auf sie", that is "and then I met her" meaning Annette. It then continues with lines taken from Ich+Ich songs.